# Configuration of .NET assembly binding of any newer assembly version in app.config <assemblyBinding>/<codeBase>

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, .net-assembly, assembly-binding-redirect

In a C# project, I use an external assembly and add it in the References of the project. Let's say the assembly is called "**ABC**" , located at compile-time **c:\complie-time\abc.dll** of version **1.0.0.0**. The "Copy Local" is set to false.

Because it is not copied local, the assembly location has to be specified in app.config.

```
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ABC"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="xyz"/>
    <codeBase version="????" href="FILE://c:/ABC-install/abc.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

The ABC assembly is provided by the ABC application installation. So at run-time, the dll is in different location **c:\ABC-install\abc.dll**.

**The question is: What should I put in the codeBase version?**

If the user install a newer version of ABC says **1.1.0.0**, and it is known to be backward compatible, the above  will not work because the .NET framework is looking for version **1.0.0.0** at **c:\ABC-install\abc.dll** if i put 1.0.0.0 there.

The condition is the at compile time we don't know what will be the version number in c:\ABC-install. All we know is it is backward compatible. The project should be able to run with all version of ABC assembly.

How to configure the app.config to allow newer version of an external assembly to be bound but runtime version is unknown at compile-time, while at complie-time the project was built based on the 1.0.0.0 dll in the reference setting?

Edit: codeBase version to ???? to show clearly the question.

Comment: do you know the difference between code base and assembly redirect?

Answer (score 0):

sample fragment  taken from a standard (I believe visual studio generated web.config ), use the bindingRedirect part.

```
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: It will redirect v1 to v2 to the run-time dll location (e.g. c:\ABC-install) where it has the v2 dll. But the point is, in c:\ABC-install the dll can be v3. .Net will not bind by your configuration because it has to find v2 there

Comment: So set newVersion to "1.0.0.0"

Comment: But the file FILE://c:/ABC-install/abc.dll can be updated to v3. It will not work when it is updated.

Comment: D you guys know the difference between code base and assembly redirect? I am not understanding it.